# insert blob via odp.net through dblink size limitations

Tags: blob, odp.net, dblink

i am using ODP.NET (version 2.111.7.0) and C#, OracleCommand & OracleParameter objects and OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method

i was wondering if there is a way to insert a big byte array into an oracle table that resides in another database, through DB link. i know that lob handling through DB links is problematic in general, but i am a bit hesitant to modify code and add another connection.

will creating a stored procedure that takes blob as parameter and talks internally via dblink make any difference? don't think so..

my current situation is that Oracle will give me "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables" whenever the parameter i pass with the OracleCommand is a byte array with length 0, or with length > 32KB (i suspect, because 20KB worked, 35KB didn't)

I am using OracleDbType.Blob for this parameter.

thank you.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using a second connection, synchronizing the two transactions so that commits and rollbacks are always performed jointly. i also ended up actually believing that there's a general issue with handling BLOBs through a dblink, so a second connection was a better choice, although in my case the design of my application was slightly disrupted - needed to introduce both a second connection and a second transaction. other option was to try and insert the blob in chunks of 32k, using PL/SQL blocks and some form of DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND, but this would require more deep changes in my code (in my case), therefore i opted for the easier and more straightforward first solution.